# MVC5 IIS7 use controller/view as 401 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, custom-error-pages

I have tried for a few days to get my MVC5 application (deployed on windows 2008r2 with iis7) to return a controller for 401. I want to be able to use this custom controller to retrieve information from the server regarding contact details to gain a user and access to the application. this server active directory is not the same as the users but they have access to that server for the web application.

NOTE: testing on VS2013 built in IIS (can also test on the 2008r2 server)

- My Application Has a **Home** controller and an **AccessDenied** controller:
- Home controller has a **custom [Authorize]** as *i have implemented my own
  second level of authentication* on top of windows auth.
- my **[CustomAuthorize]** checks if the user is valid and if true then
  checks against my database (used as a whitelist for specific users)
  and *returns false for if the user is not in the whitelist or they are
  not a valid in active directory*.
- a user logs in by using the built in **popup window** for entering credentials (chrome)
- If they **enter correctly but they are not in the white-list** they are
  **redirected to the AccessDenied** controller
- However **if the user clicks cancel**, or continuously enters invalid
  credentials the server responds with a built in **IIS 401.1, 401.2 or
  401 error**

**My Initial system.web and system.webserver** :

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="\AccessDenied" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
<!--      <deny users="?" />-->
    </authorization>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

***Result:***

- **User valid (not in whitelist):** Access Denied Controller
- **User Valid (is in whitelist):** Home Controller
- **User cancelled/incorrect credentials:** 401.2

I have tried

- HttpError tag
- [AnonymousAuthorize]
- specific  with anonymous auth (still prompts for login)

**An Additional Question:**
Is it possible to allow anonymous authentication for one controller but use windows auth for another? as my accessdenied controller is also promting for authorization (even though there is no authorize attribute)

Comment: You probably need to return a 200 OK status code and handle the Not Authorized in your view. Or better yet handle the validation for required fields in your model and have the failed authentication be an exception but still return 200 as the authentication function did return with no problem.

Comment: well upon the user clicking cancel the [authorize] attributes are never used (tested during debugging) the only control i got was in global.asax and capturing the Application_EndRequest, however when i try redirecting to my access controller it says the page is not redirecting properly.

I also tried a trick with returning 418 I'm a teapot where you force that response but IIS reported invalid response

Comment: Since you are using FormsAuthentication and you are not authorized, forms auth is trying to redirect to login, I bet. Your login method should be decorated with [Allow Anonymous]

Comment: I am using windows authentication, and have used the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the AccessDenied controller, windows auth is essential as i need to authenticate against active directory. i can return custom 401 page (AccessDenied Controller) for an authenticted user that does not exist on the whitelist but when the user presses cancel on authentication i am left with the default 401/401.1/401.2 page